# Strange plotly behavior with ggplot's coord_theta()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, polar-coordinates, ggplotly

I'm trying to render a polar ggplot in Plotly, but whenever I call `ggplotly` to do the automagic conversion for me, I get a few warnings and the polar aspect is stripped from the plot. Reproducible code below with pictures attached. **Any ideas why Plotly isn't playing nicely with ggplot when coord_theta is used?**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Generate a spread of data
x = c(0, rep(1, 5), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 23))
y = c(1, seq(0,1, length.out = 5), 
      seq(0,1, length.out = 12), 
      seq(0,1, length.out = 23))

# Create the ggplot
gp <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")

# Render the ggplot (looks fine)
gp
```

[image: A polar ggplot]

```r
# Render the plotly version
ggplotly(gp)

# WARNING MESSAGES
# 1: In min(z$x.range %||% z$x_range) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 2: In max(z$x.range %||% z$x_range) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# 3: In min(z$y.range %||% z$y_range) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 4: In max(z$y.range %||% z$y_range) :
#  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image: A ggplotly, but without the polar coordinates]

The ggplotly retains all other functionality - zooming, panning, mouseover text - it's just that the polar coordinate system has been stripped from the plot.

Comment: May be check [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/760)